# How to upload the image for the PDF to the server?

Tags: java, pdfbox, servlet-3.0

I am using PDFBox to create PDF invoice in servlet, and the image is working in the local system but whenever trying to upload it on the server, it is not working

```
PDImageXObject pdImage = PDImageXObject.createFromFile("D:\\MyProject\\src\\Img2.png", invc);
PDPageContentStream cs = new PDPageContentStream(invc, mypage);
cs.drawImage(pdImage, 42, 670);
cs.beginText();
cs.newLineAtOffset(117, 724);
cs.endText();
```

Whenever giving the local path of the image it is showing in the pdf invoice, but after making it a war file upload to the server is getting the error: "Can't read input file".

Comment: Is the image on the server, too, located at `D:\MyProject\src\Img2.png`? And does the account your web application runs as have permissions to access that file?

Comment: You may want to learn about using resources. (be careful with the filtering if you're using maven) https://mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/

Comment: Please see [ask]